# What can I do with this unzipped GDB file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, linux, file-geodatabase

I have a zip file that I got from the City department of information technology. Unzipped, it is a directory called `DOITT_ZIP_CODE_01_29JUL2009.gdb` containing a bunch of `.gdbtable` and `.gdbtablex` files. I'm not super seasoned in GIS but I'm pretty sure I ought to be able to open this in QGIS. I can't figure out a combination of parameters that will let me open it, however.

I really just need to get the data out, so I'd be happy to use something like [GDB Flee](http://gdbflee-mweisman.rhcloud.com/) but it can't seem to read the .zip and the .gdb is a directory.

Note: These instructions ([Migrating geodatabase data into PostGIS without Esri apps?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14432/how-to-migrate-gdb-data-into-postgis-without-esri-apps))  suggest I could use a command line tool, `ogr2ogr` but mine doesn't seem to have FileGDB support.

What is my next step?

Comment: might be an old GDB file, see http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/49329/187

Answer (score 2):

A couple things need to happen here:

1. GDAL has to of been compiled with ESRI FileGDB support (ie, --with-fgdb=/usr/lib/filegdb-api)
2. The FileGDB you have has to be >= v10 FileGDB
3. Open the FileGDB using QGIS:

   - **Layer** > **Add Vector Layer** > **Directory** > **Type**: **ESRI FileGDB** > *Navigate to gdb folder, highlight and press OK till you are back at map*

---

There are some instructions on how to get FileGDB support in GDAL either from [Building FGDB support for GDAL 1.10 on Ubuntu](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/72535/1297) or [install gdal with file gdb and spatialite support on ubuntu](http://hydrogeotools.blogspot.ca/2013/07/install-gdal-with-file-gdb-and.html)

Comment: I don't suppose there's a repository someplace where GDAL is already compiled with fgdb support?

Comment: Amanda, it depends on your distro - being Linux, you can compile yourself quite easily. What's your Linux distro of choice?